# Loading gif until image is fully-loaded. Then fade in

Tags: jquery

I have this set up right now: http://jsfiddle.net/FMqbP/1/

I'd like [this animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kQ8m.gif) to load until the thumbnail is finished loading and then I'd like the thumbnail to fade in. What would be the best way to go about this?

I know this can be done with the `load` function with a simple image but in my case, I need an entire div with contents in it to behave similarly.

Comment: you might probably want to look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007916/showing-loading-gif-file-while-page-gets-loaded-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could preload images using JQuery. There are several techniques for this but one I have seen is.

```
(function($) {
  var cache = [];
  // Arguments are image paths relative to the current page.
  $.preLoadImages = function() {
    var args_len = arguments.length;
    for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
      var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
      cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
      cache.push(cacheImage);
    }
  }
})(jQuery)
```

Then you can do

```
jQuery.preLoadImages("foo.gif", "/path/to/foo2.gif");
```

This solution, and more informationo about it is located at http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript