# App won't return to main activity

Tags: android, web-services

I'm new at android/java language. I have a web service that requests 2 params and returns a state (estado).
Every time i try to login with wrong user name and password the stop.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                if( "ERRO".equals(obj.getString("estado"))) {
                    errorMsg.setText(obj.getString("info"));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("info"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
```

I want to if have a wrong login to return to main activity. Can anyone help?

Comment: Start from [here](https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=show+image+while+page+is+loading)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [showing loading gif file while page gets loaded using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007916/showing-loading-gif-file-while-page-gets-loaded-using-jquery)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, this link will provide guidance on asking a good question: [ask]

Comment: You should not edit your question into an entirely different question. Please ask another question instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="init()">
    <img src="loading.gif" id="loading_gif">
    <script>
        function init(){
            window.location = "your website location";
            //But if you're planning to not redirect, but on the same website...
            document.getElementById("loading_gif").style.display = "none";
            //And then load your page here.
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

However, if you're asking to check whether **another** website is loading, you can't do that, because you haven't even started loading the website, and even if you had, I think security would prevent that. You can also use `window.onload`, which is called when the page loads (you also need to delete the `onload="init()"` if you are going to use that).